# array data filter to data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i cant filtering my data

array list is like **this**:

```
{uid: 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777 }
```

and i want filter like **this**:

```
filterdData: {
                {'index':1 , 'uid':'11111' } ........
```

Please help...

I try to ...

```
export default {
        name: 'extuserList',
        components: {
            DatePicker
        },
        data () {
            return {
                isShowForm: false,
                oid: '',
                uidList: {
                       NO:'',
                       UID:''
                       }
                originData: ['11111',222222','333333','444444' }
            }
        },

filterdData: {
                {'index':1 , 'uid':'11111' } ........
```

Comment: Notice that `arraylist` is an object

Comment: `I try to ...` what? there's no code in there that does anything `filterdData: {
                {'index':1 , 'uid':'11111' } ........` is nothing not even valid javascript

Comment: There is so much invalid JavaScript in your question that it's impossible to figure out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var a =[11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777 ];
var f =[[Math.floor(a[0]/10000),a[0]]];
var z = []
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        f =[[Math.floor(a[i]/10000),a[i]]];
    z.push(...f); 
    }
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
var t = ['11111', '222222','333333','444444'].map(function(item, index) {
    return {
       item, index 
    };
  });
```